# ArrayList<String> Custom adapter

Tags: android, sqlite

I can't do ListView adapter of ArrayList because
the whole of data is from SQLite

```
            final ArrayList<String> list= helper.GetAllValues("x1", column2);
    //final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    final ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, list, img);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public ListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.items, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TitleLabel);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.SecondLabel);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
    return rowView;

};
}
```

Error:(66, 37) error: constructor ListAdapter in class ListAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Activity,String[],Integer[]
found: Listofmeals,ArrayList,Integer[]
reason: actual argument ArrayList cannot be converted to String[] by method invocation conversion

```
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;
```

It's wrong the same as this:

```
txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
```

How type Arraylist I have to insert?

Comment: Use a Cursor Adapter.

Comment: to ListAdapter.java?

Comment: Use a CursorAdapter in place of ListAdapter

Comment: why do you need a custom adapter? why dont you use `SimplecursorAdapter` ?

Comment: I want to do Custom ListView

Comment: @Raghunandan thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you declared in your adapter takes a `String[]`, but you are passing in an `ArrayList`. Change your adapter code to use an ArrayList, or make your database helper return a `String[]` instead of an `ArrayList`. That alone should solve your compile error.

---

In my opinion, your code would be cleaner if you encapsulated all the information about an item in a class and use a single array (or list) of that type than separate arrays / lists for strings, images, etc. Something like

```
public class MyItem {
    String name;
    int imageRes;
}
```

Then you can use an `ArrayAdapter<MyItem>` with either an array or a list of `MyItem` objects.

If both the name and image id are stored in your SQLite table, then you have another option: use a `CursorAdapter` instead. In that case you would want to get a `Cursor` from your database and use that, which means you don't have to convert all the data into an array or list before using it.